# Permission denied using chrome.bluetooth.AddProfile in JS extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

I am running Google Chrome Canary on OSX.

I am trying to modify the [developer example for bluetooth application for Zephyr HXM bluetooth client](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/zephyr_hxm) to connect to an Android app which listens on a socket over Bluetooth for a specific UUID.

The dev example is using an API which is inconsistent to the later versions of Chrome which are now profile based.

When I try to call `chrome.bluetooth.addProfile({uuid: kUUID}, console.log)` in main.js of the Zephyr client I get the following error message:

`bluetooth.addProfile: Permission to add profile denied.`
followed by `Error in response to bluetooth.addProfile: TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

How do I give the extension permission to call addProfile? The manifest.json already provides bluetooth permission.

Is there a way to disable permissions globally in Chrome for testing purposes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the bluetooth permission like this in your manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
  {
    "bluetooth": [
      {
        uuid: '<Your UUID>'
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have: `"permissions": [ { "bluetooth": [ { "uuid": "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" } ] } ],` and the manifest loads correctly in Chrome. However I still receive the same error: `Error in response to bluetooth.addProfile: TypeError: Illegal invocation`. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: console.log cannot be used directly as the callback fucntion. Replace it with `function(）{console.log('ok')}`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it needs to be a packaged app and not an extension.  bluetooth wont work with extensions.